# How to replace nodes while preserving their trivia?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am trying to convert a `IEnumerable<object[]>` property

```
public IEnumerable<object[]> BeforeConversion
{
    get
    {
        yield return new object[] { new DateTime(2013, 8, 23), new DateTime(2013, 09, 15) };
        yield return new object[] { new DateTime(2013, 9, 20), new DateTime(2013, 10, 15) };
    }
}
```

to a `object[]` field

```
static object[] AfterConversion =
{
    new object[] { new DateTime(2013, 8, 23), new DateTime(2013, 09, 15) },
    new object[] { new DateTime(2013, 9, 20), new DateTime(2013, 10, 15) },
};
```

Here is my attempt:

```
var testCases = node.DescendantNodes((_) => true).OfType<ArrayCreationExpressionSyntax>()
                    .Select(i => ((ExpressionSyntax)i))
                    .ToArray();                    

var arrayType = node.DescendantNodes((_) => true).OfType<ArrayTypeSyntax>().First();

var seperators = Enumerable.Repeat(SyntaxFactory
    .Token(SyntaxKind.CommaToken)
    .WithTrailingTrivia(LineFeed), testCases.Length);
var initializerNode = SyntaxFactory       
    .ArrayCreationExpression(arrayType)
    .WithInitializer(SyntaxFactory
        .InitializerExpression(SyntaxKind.ArrayInitializerExpression)
        .WithExpressions(SyntaxFactory.SeparatedList(testCases, seperators)));

return SyntaxFactory.FieldDeclaration(
    new SyntaxList<AttributeListSyntax>(),
    SyntaxFactory.TokenList().Add(
        SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.StaticKeyword).WithTrailingTrivia(Space)),
    SyntaxFactory.VariableDeclaration(arrayType.WithTrailingTrivia(Space),
        SyntaxFactory.SeparatedList<VariableDeclaratorSyntax>().Add(
            SyntaxFactory.VariableDeclarator(newName).WithInitializer(
            SyntaxFactory.EqualsValueClause(
                SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.EqualsToken).WithLeadingTrivia(Space),
                initializerNode)))))
    .WithLeadingTrivia(node.GetLeadingTrivia())
    .WithTrailingTrivia(node.GetTrailingTrivia());
```

This implementation produces

```
static object[] TestGetExpirationDateCases =newobject[]{new object[] { new DateTime(2013, 8, 23), new DateTime(2013, 09, 15) },
 new object[] { new DateTime(2013, 9, 20), new DateTime(2013, 10, 15) },
 };
```

The formatting is quite off.  The newobject[] is one word instead of new object[].  Actually it's not needed at all, but I couldn't figure out how to create the initializer statement without it.

My questions are:
 1. Is there any way to do a quick formatting?
 2. Is there a better way to do this.  Trying to get all the details perfect seems to be time consuming.

Comment: A little off-topic, but do you know the `Cast<T>()` extension method? It allows you to write `.Cast<ExpressionSyntax>()` instead of `.Select(i => ((ExpressionSyntax)i))`.

Comment: @andyp I didn't know.  thanks.

Comment: Cast<T> actually casts all instances in the enumerable, which may not be desirable if the collection contains types that cannot be cast to T.  In these cases, use OfType<T> to enumerate all instances that are, or extend, T.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To create an array with an implicit type use an `ImplicitArrayCreationExpression` instead of an `ArrayCreationExpression`:

   ```
   var initializerNode = SyntaxFactory
       .ImplicitArrayCreationExpression(SyntaxFactory
           .InitializerExpression(SyntaxKind.ArrayInitializerExpression)
           .WithExpressions(SyntaxFactory.SeparatedList(testCases, seperators)));
   ```
2. You can format your freshly created syntax using the `Formatter`. Say you've assigned the returned results of your implementation to the variable `result`, then you can call it like this:

   ```
   using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Formatting;

   var formattedResult = Formatter.Format(result, workspace);
   ```

   Which produces this nicely formatted output for your example (I've hardcoded the name 'after'):

   ```
   static object[] after = new[]
   {
       new object[] { new DateTime(2013, 8, 23), new DateTime(2013, 09, 15) },
       new object[] { new DateTime(2013, 9, 20), new DateTime(2013, 10, 15) },
   };
   ```
3. You should try the [Roslyn Syntax Visualizer Tool](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Syntax%20Visualizer&referringTitle=Home) (View > Other Windows > Roslyn Syntax Visualizer). It allows you to look at what syntax nodes Roslyn creates for a given piece of code in your current document. This usually helps a lot when you're trying to figure out how to properly construct your own trees!

Comment: I used the Visualizer Tool to piece together my initial solution.  The formatter requires a workspace which I currently don't have.

Comment: Why not? A bit ugly I guess, but you could just create one: `var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();`

Comment: I just had a look at the [Formatter](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Formatting/Formatter.cs#286) to find out why it requires a workspace. It's just used to get a formatting service for the language (C# / VB) of the given `SyntaxNode` and an option service (if you don't pass the options as a parameter). So I think it is indeed valid to just pass in a new workspace.

Comment: Thanks.  Everything worked.  I wish they have an API site like MSDN.

Comment: That `Formatter` tool is incredible; no more fumbling around with manually adding trivia!